# Where is Java 1.8 installed on OS X El Capitan?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I just installed `jre-8u72-macosx-x64.dmg` from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html), the installation worked well.

However, when I type `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` it returns:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Does anyone know where is Java 1.8 installed?

PS: I need this to install `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers`, which requires `Java 1.8+ VM`.

Comment: It looks like you only installed the JRE.  You would need to install the JDK - once you do, the folder for Java 8 should appear under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

Comment: You should install JDK 1.8

from this link,,, currently you are downloading JRE,

JDK Link for mac


http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install JDK 1.8, currently you are using a JRE. On OS X, installing just the JRE doesn't make it available as the system default available to applications.

As of January 2016, you can download JDK 1.8 for mac from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Because Oracle tends to change their URLs, that link might go dead. Best to do a web search for "JDK mac" or something similar to find the latest version.

Comment: Thank you... I am downloading it... but why should I need JDK given that I don't need to code Java code.

Comment: because Eclipse IDE is for coding Java, so it requires Java development Kit

Comment: Actually, @DaniyalSyed, that's not accurate. Eclipse is a platform and there are many tools and applications built on it that have nothing to do with writing Java code. Technically, Eclipse *can* run on a JRE, it doesn't require a JDK (some features of the Java-oriented tools won't work without a JDK, though).

Comment: The issue is how the JRE 1.7 and above gets installed on recent versions of OS X. For some reason, they don't get installed as the system default JRE that applications can use. However, installing JDK 1.8 (or 1.7) *does* make it the default, so applications like Eclipse get it by default.

Comment: @E-Riz But i think in Question it mentions "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" so this version of eclipse requires JDK

Comment: @DaniyalSyed, not it doesn't. Eclispe IDE for Java Developers can technically run with just a JRE. Eclipse has it's own compiler so it doesn't have a strict requirement for the JDK. As I said, there are some features that won't be available if it's not running in a JDK, but it does function quite well without it.

Comment: @E-Riz oh ok Thanks for clarification. I was unaware of this.